# SharePoint 2010 Workflow on SharePoint Online Site created by Teams - Server Error: Access Denied

Tags: workflow, online, microsoft-teams

Is anyone able to save or publish a platform type: SharePoint 2010 workflow (using SharePoint designer 2013) on a SharePoint online site created as part of a Microsoft Team?

When I try to either save or publish, it gives me an error. Server Error: Access Denied

I can create 2013 workflows on the same site through SharePoint designer. I can create 2010 workflows on at least one site created not through teams as well on the same office 365 tenant.

I am a site collection admin by virtue of being in the owners group (which is automatically set up as site collection admins by Teams) and I tried switching it to being a site collection admin directly to my user account as well. I also added my account directly to the site permissions with full control, just in case.

I can't find any documentation about deprecation of SharePoint 2010 workflows on sites created via teams, but honestly there's not a lot of info on these at all.

Any further troubleshooting steps or fixes you've found?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the SPO site I use at work (it's a *Teams* site, like yours) has a few SP2010 and SP2013 workflows that we use for some utility functions.

I would...

1. [Check to see if scripting is enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script) for that site collection with either PowerShell or Central Admin
2. Ensure you have all the correct features turned on (in both *Site* and *Site Collection* features)
3. It sounds silly since you can create SP2013 WFs, but check the SP Designer settings in Site Settings and make sure all the boxes are checked
4. Lastly, do you have access to any migration tools? Might be worth a shot building a simple test SP2010 WF on a different collection and copying it over into yours.

Clearing your [SP Designer cache](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx) never hurts, either - other than the inconvenience of losing your recent sites list.

Comment: I don't have access to either powershell or Central admin, the site and site collection features exactly match a working site (non-teams based), the boxes are indeed checked for the designer settings. I'll see if I can do a migration thing.

Comment: I just updated my list of suggestions - they were all mashed together previously! If you don't have Central Admin access, can you check with the SP or Tenant admin to see if they can check that setting?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Impersonation step?
That action, witch requires admin permissions (permission of the owner of the workflow) put in Impersonation step (in 2013WF App step).

How to enable it:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Comment: Nope. It won't even save on the most basic of single action "send an e-mail" workflows.